# Why my dictionary is not updated in for loop?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have different list with some parameters which are as follows:

```
list1 = [(CODE, ADDR ), (CODE1, ADDR1)]
list2 = [(CODE2, ADDR2 ), (CODE3, ADDR3)]
list3= [list1, list2]
```

I am trying to get the parameters from this list and update my dictionary based on these parameters. In order to do that I had written the following code:

```
for i in list3 :
    for idx,j in enumerate(i):
        if idx==0:
           start_code = j[0]
           start_addr = j[1]

        CODE = j[0]
        ADDR = j[1]
        mydict.update({ADDR:CODE})
```

, but my problem is that my dictionary `mydict` is not getting updated each time and it shows me None. May I ask what could be the problem?

Comment: oof this is ugly. Can you give a sample input and expected output so it's easier to track down what it is you're expecting to have happen?

Comment: N.B. that `dict.update` returns `None` and modifies the dictionary in-place. Are you sure it's not being updated?

Comment: What is this for? `list3 = list3 = [list1, list2]`

Comment: Adam Smith This is  input example for list 1
list1 = [('b"\x66\xb8\x10\x00\x89\xea\xe8\x96\xce\xff\xff"', 0x4058cf), ('b"\xf7\xe1"', 0x402770)]. I am sure it is will not be deleted somewhere I checked that several times.

Comment: I edited that it was a mistake list3 = list3

Comment: A much nicer way of writing `mydict.update({ADDR:CODE})` is `mydict[ADDR] = CODE`

Answer (score 1):

I'm in agreement with  [Adam Smith](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3058609/adam-smith) on pointing out that `dict.update()` returns `None` (see [python docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.update)).

As an example, running your code (but replacing `list1` and `list2` element objects with strings) yields:

```
In [1]: list1 = [('CODE', 'ADDR' ), ('CODE1', 'ADDR1')]
   ...: list2 = [('CODE2', 'ADDR2' ), ('CODE3', 'ADDR3')]
   ...: list3= [list1, list2]
   ...: 

In [2]: mydict = {}

In [3]: for i in list3 :
    ...:     for idx,j in enumerate(i):
    ...:         if idx==0:
    ...:            start_code = j[0]
    ...:            start_addr = j[1]
    ...: 
    ...:         CODE = j[0]
    ...:         ADDR = j[1]
    ...:         mydict.update({ADDR:CODE})
    ...:         

In [4]: mydict
Out[4]: {'ADDR': 'CODE', 'ADDR1': 'CODE1', 'ADDR2': 'CODE2', 'ADDR3': 'CODE3'}
```